# why we use SSL/TLS tunnelling instead of creating new secure protocol

Tags: tls

I don't know why people use  tunelling SSL instead of creating safce protocol like HTTPS. 
Could you have an idea ?

Comment: Perhaps you should do some research to understand if there is a relation between HTTPS and SSL/TLS.

Comment: HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS.

Comment: lol - that's exactly what HTTPS is: HTTP tunneled over SSL.

Comment: you don't understand my question. The question is; Why nobody doesn't think a new protocol which will be secuire (as HTTPS/SMTPS), but it will not require SSL tunel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a new protocol to replace SSL/TLS would make sense only if the new protocol was "better" in some substantial way. Though SSL/TLS has a few known shortcomings, making anything better is harder (much harder) than it may seem.

And people who are working on that have decided that it should still be called TLS. [TLS-1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-11), to be precise.